# LoadRunner 12,Open VGU error, as shown below, I hope you can give me advice, thank you very much

Tags: loadrunner

System. ArgumentNullException: value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path.

[image]

Comment: Add more error details like steps, lib, code...

Answer (score 0):

It seems your installation is corrupted. Can you please try to reinstall VuGen.